# Meaning of D[f[x,y],x,y]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In calculus, we show our students:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
$$

Now, in Mathematica, which of the following matches this second partial derivative: D[f[x,y],x,y] or D[f[x,y],y,x]?

I am aware of Clairaut's rule and this probably won't be an issue (as counterexamples usually involve limit use), but like double integrals, I find the ordering sometimes confusing.

Comment: As noted in the docs, it will succesively differentiate in the order of the variables given to it.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. True. I read the documentation. So which do you pick?

Comment: Well, you differentiated with respect to `y`first before `x`, so... ;) with respect to multiple integrals, the convention of "outermost limits first" can be admittedly confusing at first.

Comment: Use `D[f[x, y], x, y] // Trace`

Answer (score 2):

```
TraditionalForm[HoldForm @ D[f[x, y], x, y]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

D[f[x,y],x,y] first differentiates with respect to x, then to y!

Simply test it with ToString[y]:

```
In[18]:= f[x_, y_] = Sin[x y]

In[19]:= D[f[x, y], x, ToString[y]] // Quiet

Out[19]= D[y Cos[x y], y]

In[20]:= D[f[x, y], ToString[y], x] // Quiet

Out[20]= D[Sin[x y], y, x]
```

both stop at the first ToString[...].